# How in Angular JS obtain and send a picture?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, base64

I have URL that I am trying to get a picture from. I'm using the `$http.get()` method, but get a binary response. How can I get something back that I can insert into the page?

```
$http.get('https://exampleurl/images/' + $scope.element[i].id)
                            .success(function (response) {
          // I have response such as: ""����JFIF``��;CREATOR gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80)"
                            });
```

Comment: why don't you just create an `img` element instead of using an xhr?

Comment: How to do it? I never did it.

Comment: @roan.harez May I ask why ajax ?

Comment: I did not get to display an image.

Comment: @roan.harez Ok. but when you have URL of an IMG , you can create IMG and just set its SRC to that URL. is it ok ? if so - then see Daniel's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `img` element and don't use `$http.get`.

```
var imageElement = angular.element('<img />').attr('src', yourUrl);
// insert imageElement somewhere else
```

Comment: AFAIK he doesn't have the image url but bytes.

Comment: if he's using `$http.get` then he must.

Comment: I've just noticed that he actually go to a img url `https://exampleurl/images/`. I don't know why i was thinking that he goes to a server which generates an img.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a solution!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you asked for:

> How in Angular JS obtain and send a picture?

So, let's look at both... Actually, we've got 3 problems: the 3rd one is some bug. You've already said:

> but get a binary response

If you just can get "binary" from the URL, it means the HTTP response has some lack of CONTENT-TYPE for the correct MIME-TYPE of. You need to solve it with:

> Content-type: image/jpeg

All right?

**HOW TO SEND PICTURES**

*Do not convert it to base64 if design pattern matters for you*. Because you just need to handle the REST properly. Also, you couldn't want to increase the POST request size by converting the BLOB into BASE64 code.

It has one JavaScript resource called [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) for the God's sake.

Look at here: [Multipart/form-data File Upload with AngularJS](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

You can figure out with jQuery too:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
url: "stash.php",
type: "POST",
data: fd,
processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
});
```

**HOW TO GET IMAGES**

Why can't you just tag'em? The IMG elements can load it without any hurt. You just would need their URL addresses.